# How to increase visibility_timeout

Tags: python-2.7, django-celery, django-1.4

We're using Django 1.4.22 and celery 3.1.25 with REDIS. The default value for visibility_timeout is one hour and it is too small for our jobs.

**How can we increase visibility_timeout to 6 hours?**

My attempt was to set in Dkjango's setting.py this:

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600 * 6}
```

I do not remember where I got this recommendation from. If you know any other solution, please advise. So far, I couldn't find anything that works.

-- EDIT --

When running:

```
manage.py celery inspect conf
```

It shows:

```
...
"BROKER_TRANSPORT": null,
"BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS": {},
...
```

Comment: Hi, as per the celery documentation it says `broker_transport_options = {'visibility_timeout': 18000}  # 5 hours` Please check this [link](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-broker_transport_options)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I see here that older versions of Celery (until 4.0) still expect configuration in uppercase, which we did:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings
Is there a way to "pprint" Celery settings to see what values do we find there when we are actually using it?

Answer (score 0):

Correct celery option names start with **CELERY_** prefix

In your case **CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS**